# Access 2013 - Textbox searching in two fields

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a simple database for tracking incidents at work.  On the main form is a subform that shows a brief overview of all events logged.

I have a search box in the subform's header that searches keywords in the "Details" field, but I would like it to also search in the "Location" field of the subform at the same time.

My code is:

```
Private Sub Text18_Change()
Dim strFilter As String

Me.Refresh

strFilter = "Details like '*" & Me.Text18 & "*'"

Forms![Main Form]![MainIncidentList].Form.Filter = strFilter
Forms![Main Form]![MainIncidentList].Form.FilterOn = True

Me.Text18.SelStart = Nz(Len(Me.Text18), 0)
End Sub
```

I'm relatively new at Access and VBA but I've gotten this far, can anyone give me some advice on how to add the "Location" field to the search?  I've tried adding

```
" And "Location like '*" & "Me.Text18 & "*'"
```

at the end of the "strFilter" line, but it did not work, Access gives a syntax error.

Both "Details" and "Location" are defined as "long text" in the table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
strFilter = "Details like '*" & Me.Text18 & "*' OR Location like '*" & Me.Text18 & "*'"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but Access gave a "Compile Error: Syntax Error".  I was under the impression that the "OR" operator had to be inside double-quotes as well, I tried that but Access gave an expression error too.